# echo background-image

Tags: php, echo

I am trying echo a background-image inside a `.phtml` to send an email.

However i am having troubles with the quotes. The image is not shown.

```
<?php echo '
    Plataforma <a href="http://xxxx.com/">http://xxxx.com/</a>
    <br>
    <div style="width:220px; height:30px; background-color:black; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url("http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg")"></div>
'
?>
```

The IDE validate this code as correct, but the image is not shown in the email that is sent.

Comment: a few of the major email clients don't support the background-image keep that in mind. Including outlook 07,10 and 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers fixed the problem (gmail, hotmail). This will work

```
<?php echo '
    Plataforma <a href="http://xxxx.com/">http://xxxx.com/</a>
    <br>
    <div style="width:220px; height:30px; background-color:black;">
        <img src="http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg">
    </div>
    '; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo '
    Plataforma <a $href="http://xxxx.com/">http://xxxx.com/</a>
    <br>
    <div $style="width:220px; height:30px; background-color:black; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url(\"http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg\")"></div>
    '
?>
```

Value of style attribute is enclosed by double quotes, so any double quota inside must be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
background-image:url("http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg")
```

to:

```
background-image:url('http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg')
```

The double quotes are cutting off your DOM in the wrong place, causing it to mis-read.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is invalid. Change this line:

```
background-image:url("http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg")
```

to read like this:

```
background-image:url('http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg')
```

Because it's inside a style="" attribute, the " symbols in the background-image line are signalling the end of the style attribute instead of the path for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single escaped quotes, like this in URL of image:

```
<?php echo '
    Plataforma <a href="http://xxxx.com/">http://xxxx.com/</a>
    <br>
    <div style="width:220px; height:30px; background-color:black; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url(\'http://www.inova-ria.pt/images/UebeImg/Thumb/Img_153_363_T.jpg\')"></div>
'
?>
```